# VMO Changes After Adding New RAM To AIX?

Tags: memory, java, aix

We have a server at a client site running AIX 5.3, which we just up the RAM to 32GB, from initially 16GB (if I'm not mistaken).

This server is our Application server running J2EE applications on top of Oracle Internet Application Server. Recently we encountered one of the batch jobs hitting out of memory error.

From NMON I see that on average, there's 5GB of free memory available. `%MAXPERM` is set to '15' and `%MINPERM` is '5'. `lru_file_repage` is '0'. `%comp` is around '70' and `%numperm` is '15'.

I would like to ask:

1. After adding real memory to the server, is there any additional changes we  need to do to the VMO?
2. Is the `%MAXPERM` too low?